# JMS Counting the number of pending messages in a topic domain

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic, tibco

First of all sorry for the new topic created. I did it because unfortunately the others was not very clear to me.

**Problem.**
I'd like to know if it's possible to count the number of messages pending in a topic sub/pub. 
I am using tomcat and activemq in the test enviroment but I am going to use Tibco in the real enviroment. Is there a simple and generic way for do that.

**Obs**
 
I have already implemented a consumer cliente with pure JMS and it can receive all message from its topic very well.

Comment: Topic messages are generally not 'queued', therefore, there is no such thing as a count. When sending to a topic, messages are consumed by all available subscribers, brokers don't save messages for subscribers unless they are durable.

Answer (score 1):

For your development environment, if you use ActiveMQ and want to see the number of pending messages in a topic/queue, you can use JMX support of ActiveMQ to monitor JMS topic/queue. A good introduction on using JMX for ActiveMQ is given in [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/managing-activemq-jmx-apis). Note that once you have an intance of [`QueueViewMBean`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.9.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/QueueViewMBean.html), you can get the number of messages yet to be sent by calling [`getQueueSize`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.9.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/DestinationViewMBean.html#getQueueSize%28%29) method. For Tibco broker, I don't know if they provide similar functionality as ActiveMQ. I think it depends on different JMS broker implementations.

Comment: There is a subclass of DestinationViewMBean: TopicViewMBean. This class inherits the same `getQueueSize` method from its base class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the TIBCO GEMS (graphical EMS admin) tool?
It's downloadable for free on the tibcommunity website

GEMS can display you pending messages for a durable subscriber ona a TIBCO EMS topic

Comment: No, I am notfamiliar with TIBCO GMS and have to build my own java application to get this infomations about Tibco (ems). I succeced with JMX and Activemq but I do not know if it's possible to do the same with a tibco ems topic. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Sure you can do. Actually GEMS is build with the EMS Admin API. Check the documentation (it contains the javadocs) on: https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-enterprise-message-service.   If you can't access that (some docs are restricted), try to download the trial EMS that comes with full documentation: http://tap.tibco.com/storefront/index.ep

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

First of all, thank you everbody who helped me. I have finished this task a couple of weeks ago but unfortunately I wasn't able to share with you what I did to solve it. The concept of JMS wasn't very clear into my mind and from my point of view it was pivotal for the problem solution.

**To begin with, informations related to pending messages is cointained into provider.**
 
Each provider implements its all classes to deal with this kind of information.

**Tibco jars**
Tibco provides a jar called tibjmsadmin there you can find all informations such as statistics related to a topic or queue.

**Solution**
As solution the tibjmsadmin was implemented into my project, therefore  the access to topic's  information is being made through its classes.

tibjmsadmin: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.3.0-february-2012/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/admin/package-summary.html

oracle specification: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/docs-136352.html